# Nginx log_format being ignored

Tags: nginx, proxypass

I'm looking for a little help with the log_format function in Nginx.  I'm using if statements (yeah, if is evil, I know) to select the upstream pool based on argument values and things aren't working right.  I really need to log what upstream server is used - heck, if I could log the $pool variable, that'd be great too.

No matter what I try or where I put the log_format, it's still logging in the default 'combined' format.  I've looked at all the config files that are included in starting up nginx and log_format is only defined in one place.

Any ideas?  Here's the pertinent parts of my configs:

**nginx.conf/http context:**

```
   log_format auditing '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                ' "$host" "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $proxy_host '
                ' $upstream_addr $http_soapaction';

    map $request $loggable
    {
            ~*app_ping\.d911 0;
            default 1;
    }


    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log auditing; #combined if=$loggable
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
```

**sites-enabled/site-specific/server context:**

```
    access_log /var/log/nginx/producttest.log auditing;

set $pool "def-pool-443";    ### Set the default pool (will be TAS pool in prod)

            ### Modify target pool depending on criteria match
            if ($args ~* 'device_type=bot')
                    {
                    set $pool "bot-pool-443";
                    }
    ...

    location /
            {
            access_log /var/log/nginx/productest-location.log auditing;
            proxy_pass https://$pool;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500;
    proxy_connect_timeout 2;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, well, after days of beating my head against the wall, I answered my own question while formatting it for posting.

I followed an online example of how to format the log_format and turns out it didn't like the single-ticks used for line-wrapping.  I took those out and put it all on a single line and presto.

Anyway, hope this helps someone else who followed the same example.